# Показ диалога без invokeLater в EDT

Tags: многопоточность, java, swing

Можно ли показывать диалог из EDT (`Event-Dispatch-Thread`) в многопоточном приложении? То есть вызывать у диалога метод `setVisible(true)`.

Например, у меня есть обработчик нажатия кнопки. Там мы оказываемся в EDT и вызываем `setVisible(true)` у какого-нибудь диалога. А преподаватель спрашивает, может ли на что-то повлиять, если мы будем открывать диалог в `invokeLater` (типа должно стать лучше). Внутри метода `setVisible` стоит условие, что если мы в EDT, то сразу запускаем, а иначе - в `invokeLater`. А тут предлагается принудительно вызывать `invokeLater`.

Я проверил; оказалось, разницы никакой. А преподаватель спрашивает, в чем разница и почему это плохо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кдинтсвенная проблема, которая приходит в голову, так это то, что другие обработчики кнопки могут оказаться в обломе. В остальном же ничего опасного быть не должно, если вы делаете это из правильного потока. Разве что по какой-то причине "наступите сами себе на хвост" и схватите dead-lock, но это должно быть что-то специфическое..

Comment: Ответ подошел :)